# How to create event replicating changes in predefined sheets to other workbooks?

Tags: vba, excel, events, replication

I have many workbooks with some of them having the same sheets. I am wondering if I can create event replicating changes from one sheet to the same sheet in many other workbooks in predefined localization. Is possible to use here somehow Worksheet_Change so that each change would be replicated??

Comment: what is predefined localization? on same pc or on network ? If you give detail information, you might get some answer.

Comment: Currently I am trying to do this on my own drive. For example in C:\Excel I have about 20 workbooks with different risk data, however, some of sheets are almost the same. Say for example, each have "Vega" sheet. So is it possible to trigger an event which would replicate changes from one workbook in sheet "vega" to all other workbooks with this tab?